# Mix Qt qmake Makefile with custom Makefiles

Tags: c++, qt, arm

I'm trying to embed Qt on an ARM system, in order to use a touchscreen with my own application. Everything works fine. In fact I already made a small standalone application to test and it runs perfect.

Now I need this Qt application to be linked with the others applications on my system.

The thing is, we have our own `Makefile` system that creates the packages and other things, and then we just have to send the *.deb* to the ARM system and unpacked it to have the software installed. By the way, these makefiles have special rules. But I need the Qt makefile's rules too, in order to be able to compile.

Is there a way to mix Qt Makefile and my Makefile? Do you have an idea?

Comment: It is not clear, you use qmake and GNU make. Or you have GNU make's files for build qt and deb files?

Comment: @user1034749 - The way I read it they need to integrate some of their own custom Makefile rules into qmake's Makefile. The custom rules are specifically used to package the project into .deb files.

Comment: That's the idea, we need to have our custom rules (package generation, ...) and Qt's rules to include Qt library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally solved the problem : we call `qmake` in our own makefile to create a makefile for Qt ; then we simply make the Qt makefile and then create our packages.
We had another link issue, but we solved it by linking the good libs in the *.pro* ; that was quite easy in fact x)

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Q_MAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS to add your custom targets.

> The other lesser known variable is QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS, this is useful when you want to be able to add a custom build target to your Makefile. For example, if you wanted to have a target to update your qm file for your application.

from [The power of qmake](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/)

Comment: Actually it's not just a target, our makefile defined quite a lot of things and execute some commands that we need to cross-compile our application.
I tryed to use `$(MAKE) -f` with the makefile generated by qmake but I've got link errors... Which I think is quite logic, 'cause Qt can't know our libs ; and our basic tool can't know Qt libs.. So I don't really know what to do now :/